Oracle 11g and EF Core 8 two similar servers one throws an error "OracleException: ORA-28040"
Looking for some help/advice.
I have two Oracle 11g servers call them "TEST" and "PROD". When I run my project it connects fine to "TEST" but when trying to run it with "PROD" I get

OracleException: ORA-28040: The database does not accept your client's authentication protocol; login denied.

Both servers are v11.2.0.4.
The project is .NET 8 with EF Core 8.0.7 and Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore v8.23.50
In Program.cs, I have:
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
{
     options.UseOracle(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("test"),
x => x.UseOracleSQLCompatibility(
        Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.OracleSQLCompatibility.DatabaseVersion19
)).EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
              .LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information);
}, ServiceLifetime.Singleton);

My connection strings (all correct and tested elsewhere (Oracle SQL Developer, just ManagedDataAccess.Client)):
"prod": "User Id=***;Password=****;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=productionIP)(PORT=****)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=prod)));"
"test": "User Id=***;Password=****;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=testIP)(PORT=****)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=test)));"

SQLNET.ORA is identical on both servers, same for listener.ora and tnsnames.ora.
Both servers are accessible.
I am able to access both with version 7 of the Entity Framework setting compatibility to "11" and also with ManageDataAccess.Client. But with EF Core 8 only the "test" server works.

i face the same issue in our environment
after a lot of search and asking professional developer
he put these two line of code inside

Program.cs

and before

builder.Services.AddDbContext

OracleConfiguration.SqlNetAuthenticationServices = "none";
OracleConfiguration.SqlNetAllowedLogonVersionClient = OracleAllowedLogonVersionClient.Version11;

after that the issue gone
